# Can I override doesNotRecognizeSelector in Swift ,so that app won't crash for some Selector?

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my Code:

```
class RNObserverManager: NSObject {
var observers:Set<NSObject> = []

override func doesNotRecognizeSelector(aSelector: Selector){
    var isRecognized = false
    for observer in observers{
        if observer.respondsToSelector(aSelector){
            observer.performSelector(aSelector)
            isRecognized = true
        }
    }
    if  !isRecognized{
        super.doesNotRecognizeSelector(aSelector)
    }
}
}
```

App crashes no matter I call  `super.doesNotRecognizeSelector(aSelector)`  or not.
I war trying to override `doesNotRecognizeSelector()`,so that my custom class can dynamic respond to some Selector.

1.if I call `super.doesNotRecognizeSelector(aSelector)`

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ObserverTrampoline.RNObserverManager doSomething]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdfebdb42e0'

2. if I don't call `super.doesNotRecognizeSelector(aSelector)`

> EXC_BREAKPOINT

Comment: Any log or stacktrace? Did you try debug the problem by stepping thru the code?

Comment: I would try to find out why this is happening (it is definitely a bug) instead of sweeping it under the rug and pretend it does not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to dynamically handle unrecognized messages without crashing, you should override `forwardInvocation:` (and `methodSignatureForSelector:`) in Objective-C (they are not available in Swift). If you just need to forward it to one observer, then a simpler way is to override `forwardingTargetForSelector:` (which is available in Swift), but if you want to do more than one, or need to do other complicated stuff, you need `forwardInvocation:`.